# GAE datastore foreign key and join

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, one-to-many, cascade, join

i'm struggling with gae for something that looks very simple to me.
let me explain.
i have a table with data about a person, i decided to use email as id

```
@Entity
public class Person{
@Id
@Column(name = "email")
String email;
...
```

what i would like to accomplish is

1. create a table with two columns, both containing email from Person, with the meaning "email in column 1 has written to email in column 2"
2. when i delete a row from Person, i would like that all the rows in the table at point 1 that contain this Person email in column 1 or 2 would be deleted as a cascade effect
3. i want to query my database so that, given an email address, i will be able to join all the rows in the table at point 1 and extract all the datas (name, phone...) of the Persons the given email has written to.

trouble is that apparently in gae i cannot use join, and i simply can't understand how to create a join table with cascade effect.
any help is welcome.
thanks in advance

Comment: The GAE datastore is not a relational database. Don't try to use it as one.

Answer (score 0):

Datastore isn't a relational database, so you should [familiarise yourself](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) with the concepts before starting to design a solution.  What you're trying to do is fit a square peg into a round hole: not only will you find you're missing joins, you will also have to implement your own cascade-on-delete (hint: you may not want to do this but if you did, and you have a lot of data, look at [Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/)).

You don't provide much in the way of code, and I don't know JPA (tip: look at [Objectify](https://github.com/objectify/objectify), it's much more suitable for the non-relational Datastore) but you might want something like this (using *Objectify* annotations):

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    String email;
    ...
}
```

Then I'm assuming you will have some kind of `Message` entity (what you refer to as a two-column table):

```
@Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    Long msgId;
    @Index
    Ref<Person> from;
    @Index
    Ref<Person> to;
    ...
}
```

Depending on what queries you need to perform, you may need to create a custom index (read [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes)).  Remember, queries on Datastore are index scans.

But, say, you want to get messages sent from `Person A` to `Person B`, you can do something like:

```
Person a = ofy().load().type(Person.class).id("a@example.com").now();
Person b = ofy().load().type(Person.class).id("b@example.com").now();
...
ofy().load().type(Person.class).filter("from =", Ref.create(a)).filter("to =", Ref.create(b)).list();
```

Instead of using `Ref<Person>` (essentially a [`Key`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities)), you could of course use a String representing the email.  You may also not want to use `email` as the `@Id` as that would prevent a user changing their email address.